# How can I split a 5 consecutive numeric digits from a string? (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have the following sample of Spanish addresses data where I need to extract the postal code (5 numeric digits in the end of the string) from it:

```
Carrer Arquebisbe Aspareg, No. 5D, Planta 1, Puerta B, Palma de Mallorca, 07007, Balears, Illes
Avenida de Turruñuelos, No. 1, Bloque Portal 1, Planta 2, Puerta J, Córdoba, 14012, Córdoba
Rua Celso Emilio Ferreiro, No. 38, Planta 1º, Puerta A, Pontes de García Rodríguez, As, 15320, Coruña, A
Calle Del Mayoral, No. 20, Planta 1, Puerta Sin Pta, Zaragoza, 50003, Zaragoza
Calle Trovero Cantares, No. 2, Planta 2DO, Puerta A, Unión, La, 30360, MurciaCamiño Toural De Adentro, No. 24, Planta 1, Puerta IZQ, Vigo, 36207, Pontevedra
Carretera Valencia, No. 41, Planta Bajo, Puerta Izq, Bétera, 46117, Valencia/València
Calle Alcocer, No. 22, Planta 6, Puerta A, Madrid, 28041, Madrid
Carrer Santa Teresa, No. 11, Planta 1, Puerta 4, Cerdanyola del Vallès, 08290, Barcelona
Carrer Esquadres, No. 24 - D, Planta atico, Puerta 5, Hospitalet de Llobregat, L, 08901, Barcelona
```

The only rule I can find: it's always 5 consecutive numeric digits. It's not always in the penultimate index(splitting by coma). I tried the following solution:

```
int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, my_string)))
```

But it doesn't work because I have other numeric characters in the beginning of the string (i.e. house number). Anyone that can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this a string or a dataframe?

Comment: It is a df, not a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regex.

```py
    import re

    text = """Carrer Arquebisbe Aspareg, No. 5D, Planta 1, Puerta B, Palma de Mallorca, 07007, Balears, Illes
    Avenida de Turruñuelos, No. 1, Bloque Portal 1, Planta 2, Puerta J, Córdoba, 14012, Córdoba
    Rua Celso Emilio Ferreiro, No. 38, Planta 1º, Puerta A, Pontes de García Rodríguez, As, 15320, Coruña, A
    Calle Del Mayoral, No. 20, Planta 1, Puerta Sin Pta, Zaragoza, 50003, Zaragoza
    Calle Trovero Cantares, No. 2, Planta 2DO, Puerta A, Unión, La, 30360, MurciaCamiño Toural De Adentro, No. 24, Planta 1, Puerta IZQ, Vigo, 36207, Pontevedra
    Carretera Valencia, No. 41, Planta Bajo, Puerta Izq, Bétera, 46117, Valencia/València
    Calle Alcocer, No. 22, Planta 6, Puerta A, Madrid, 28041, Madrid
    Carrer Santa Teresa, No. 11, Planta 1, Puerta 4, Cerdanyola del Vallès, 08290, Barcelona
    Carrer Esquadres, No. 24 - D, Planta atico, Puerta 5, Hospitalet de Llobregat, L, 08901, Barcelona"""

    postcodes = re.findall('\d{5}',text)
    print(postcodes)
```

> ['07007',  '14012',  '15320',  '50003',  '30360',  '36207',  '46117',  '28041',  '08290',  '08901']

regex stands for regular expressions. Some websites help you figuring it out, like https://regexr.com/

Comment: Indeed, this would make sense.

Comment: pandas has methods to work with regex under `.str.`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
addresses = []
for line in input():
  for string in line.split(','):
    if len(string) == 5 and all(char.isdigit() for char in string):
      addresses.append(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re looking for is regular expressions. You could probably match any digits with length of five with something similar to this:

```
postal_codes = re.findall(“\d{5}”, text)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV format is reliably present, you could use a CSV parser and extract the sixth field:

```
import csv
csvmode = 'r'
with open('filename', csvmode) as addrfile:
    cc = csv.reader(addrfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in cc:
        print (row[5])
```

However, running this on your sample data, it seems there are a variable number of fields present, so may this is not a good solution for you:

```
07007
Córdoba
As
50003
La
46117
28041
08290
```